# Why might an EF Core 7 query be slow only sometimes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, ef-core-7.0

I'm using EF Core 7 as the ORM in a Blazor Server application that I am writing. Most of my queries are small and don't cause any problems. However, I have one large query that will generally execute in under 10ms, but every now and then the execution time will spike to > 6,000ms, sometimes even going past 10,000ms. There is no consistency as to when I see the spike in my logs. A sample of the execution times is included below:
[image]

If I keep repeating the same query over and over again within the application sometimes the spike will come after 5 repeats, sometimes it will take more than 50 repetitions. If I repeat the query using the generated SQL in SSMS the execution time seems consistent and fast. Looking at the Execution Plan the biggest cost with the query seems to be associated with sorts, which account for 11% each, while the rest of the nodes in the plan are 2% or less. But I don't really know how to use this fact to improve the query. I have minimal experience with databases and this is the first project on which I have used EF Core, so my inexperience is certainly showing here.

I have included the offending query below. It is almost certainly horrendously inefficient as it joins on many tables to bring in navigation properties all the way down the object hierarchy. At this time I am still testing the application and each table only has a small number of rows, < 10 in most cases. I have tried using split queries but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I know that projection would probably improve performance, but I do need all of the data in the object hierarchy, and due to some poor design decisions made early on in the project I am using the entity classes rather than DTOs and view models. Design decisions aside, I am still perplexed as to why the slowdown occurs seemingly at random.

```
bike = await dbContext.Bikes
                    .Include(bike => bike.FrameProfile)
                    .Include(bike => bike.BikeConfigurations)
                        .ThenInclude(bikeConfig => bikeConfig.ForkConfiguration)
                            .ThenInclude(forkConfig => forkConfig.Damper)
                                .ThenInclude(forkDamper => forkDamper.CompressionTune)
                                    .ThenInclude(compressionTune => compressionTune.MappedProduct)
                    .Include(bike => bike.BikeConfigurations)
                        .ThenInclude(bikeConfig => bikeConfig.ForkConfiguration)
                            .ThenInclude(forkConfig => forkConfig.Damper)
                                .ThenInclude(forkDamper => forkDamper.ReboundTune)
                                    .ThenInclude(reboundTune => reboundTune.MappedProduct)
                    .Include(bike => bike.BikeConfigurations)
                        .ThenInclude(bikeConfig => bikeConfig.ForkConfiguration.Spring)
                    .Include(bike => bike.BikeConfigurations)
                        .ThenInclude(bikeConfig => bikeConfig.ForkConfiguration.SuspensionProduct)
                    .Include(bike => bike.BikeConfigurations)
                        .ThenInclude(bikeConfig => bikeConfig.ShockConfiguration)
                            .ThenInclude(shockConfig => shockConfig.Damper)
                                .ThenInclude(shockDamper => shockDamper.CompressionTune)
                                    .ThenInclude(compressionTune => compressionTune.MappedProduct)
                    .Include(bike => bike.BikeConfigurations)
                        .ThenInclude(bikeConfig => bikeConfig.ShockConfiguration)
                            .ThenInclude(shockConfig => shockConfig.Damper)
                                .ThenInclude(shockDamper => shockDamper.ReboundTune)
                                    .ThenInclude(reboundTune => reboundTune.MappedProduct)
                    .Include(bike => bike.BikeConfigurations)
                        .ThenInclude(bikeConfig => bikeConfig.ShockConfiguration.Spring)
                    .Include(bike => bike.BikeConfigurations)
                        .ThenInclude(bikeConfig => bikeConfig.ShockConfiguration.SuspensionProduct)
                    .Include(bike => bike.BikeConfigurations)
                        .ThenInclude(bikeConfig => bikeConfig.Wheels)

                    .AsSplitQuery()
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .TagWith("Load complete Bike from database")
                    .SingleAsync(a => a.Id == id, cancellationToken);
```

Any assistance on how to better profile the query or improve the query itself is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) to see what is going on here on the SQL Server itself.  I would have guessed it's taking a long time to re-establish the connection to the database, except that would usually be for the *first* query after a pause instead of the *last* query.  Your data shows that it's the *last* query.

You might also check to make sure your app isn't going to sleep.  Also it depends on what's between the application and the SQL Server.  If there's a VPN there it may be going to sleep and need to reconnect.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into the profiler. I can rule out any intermediate steps between the application and the SQL server as they're both running locally on my machine. I do spin up a DbContext on every access to the database so your thought on re-establishing the connection being slow has some merit.

Comment: @waffleShirt _"I do spin up a DbContext on every access to the database so your thought on re-establishing the connection being slow has some merit."_ - `DbContext` was designed to be lightweight so you can throw away instances and create when needed (also you can look into DbContextFactory if you have some doubts here), it should use connection pooling, so the re-establishing the connection should not be a problem, especially one leading to second delays. Check what EXACT query is executed with which EXACT parameters and try to recreate it with SSMS or another tool.